# getStaticPaths is required for dynamic SSG

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am new to Next.js and
I've been trying to to use  `getStaticProps` in my dynamic pages in my Next.js app
and I get this error:

> Error: getStaticPaths is required for dynamic SSG pages and is missing
> for '/query/[itmid]'

`[itmid].jsx`

```
function Query({ posts }) {
  
  return (
 
        {posts.map((itm, k) => {
          return (
            <>
              <Head>
                <title> {itm.Name} - wixten </title>
              </Head>
            
              <div key={itm._id} className="Question-one">
                <h1> {itm.Name}</h1>
                <h2>{itm.Summary}</h2>
              </div>
              <div className="username">
                <span className="username2">--{itm.username}</span>
              </div>
            </>
          );
        })}
      </>
   
  
      <div className="multi-container">
        <Answershooks id={gotid} />
        <RealtedPost />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
 
  const res = await fetch("https://ask-over.herokuapp.com/questone/" + gotid);
  console.log("check");
  console.log("dada");
  const posts = await res.json();

  return {
    props: {
      posts,
    },
  };
}
export default Query;
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: You have to export a `getStaticPaths` function when using a dynamic page with `getStaticProps`. However, you can return an empty `paths` array from `getStaticPaths` and use `fallback: 'blocking'` if you don't want to pre-generate pages at build time.

Comment: i want pre-generate pages

Comment: Then specify the paths that need to be pre-generated in `paths` like suggested in the answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71029865/1870780. Make sure the `params` match the dynamic page name too, in your case `itmid`.

Comment: @juliomalves can u pls tell me how i can convert this into getServerSideProps

Comment: Why do you need to convert this to `getServerSideProps`? That's a completely different question.

Comment: the thing is i want to pass the values as the  first HTML response needs to include those tags. you can see that by using View Source

Comment: And you can achieve that with either `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps`. I'd highly recommend you have a read through the official data fetching docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/overview.

Comment: which method should i try?

Comment: can u help me with  getServerSideProps

Answer (score 1):

What `getStaticProps` does is to generate the static page, but you need to tell next js, **what are the paths to generate?**

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {

    return {
      paths: [
          { params: { query: 'slug-1' }}, 
          { params: { query: 'slug-2' }}
      ],
      fallback: true // false or 'blocking'
    };
  }
```

Then in your getStaticProp

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
 
  //params.query will return slug-1 and slug-2
  const res = await fetch("https://ask-over.herokuapp.com/questone/" + params.query);
  console.log("check");
  console.log("dada");
  const posts = await res.json();

  return {
    props: {
      posts,
    },
  };
}
```

You need to use `params.query` if you name your file `[query].js`.

The above codes will generate static paths `/slug-1` and `/slug-1`.

If you are not trying to generate static pages (which seems like it), then you should probably use `getServerSideProps` which generates page on the go.

Comment: or - Error: A required parameter (itmid) was not provided as a string in getStaticPaths for /query/[itmid]

Comment: i am gettign this error

Comment: like error state, because your itemid is not a string. it needs to be a string.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-dew-u1jtt?file=/src/App.js   i have added the entire code here can u pls tell me what i need to change

Comment: your `https://ask-over.herokuapp.com/question/` is not returning anything. What is `gotid` ?

Comment: i have to pass a id as    var goid = router.query.itmid;        "https://ask-over.herokuapp.com/questone/" + gotid   like this only it will work

Comment: Refer to my answer, change slug-1 slug-2 to your ID. Then instead of `gotid`, use `params.query` e.g. `"https://ask-over.herokuapp.com/questone/" + params.query`

Comment: meaning instead of `{ params: { query: 'slug-1' }}`, it should be `{ params: { query: 'your got id here' }}`

Comment: https://ask-over.herokuapp.com/questone/616c5abf4943a60023306ead

Comment: How do you access your page? `example.com/page?goid=616c5abf4943a60023306ead`? or `example.com/616c5abf4943a60023306ead`

Comment: http://localhost:3000/query/616c5abf4943a60023306ead

Comment: then follow my answer codes exactly as it is. You should not be using `router.query.itemid`, you should be using `params.query` and name your js file `[query].js`

Comment: https://wixten.com/query/616c5abf4943a60023306ead    currently i access it like this

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-perlman-x0kwn

Comment: Please do remember to **read my answers** entirely. You are doing some, but not following everything. Including naming your page `[query].js`

Comment: paths: [{ params: { query: "616c5abf4943a60023306ead" } }],  i cant do this  i cannot hardcode here

Comment: Then use `getServerSideProps`, don't use `getStaticProps`

Comment: paths: [{ params: { query: router.query.itmid } }],  i want to do something like this

Comment: i am new to nextjs can u pls help me with what changes i must do to make this getServerSideProps

Comment: replace `getStaticProps` with `getServerSideProps`

Comment: thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'You can not use getStaticProps or getStaticPaths with getServerSideProps. To use SSG, please remove getServerSideProps', crates/core/src/next_ssg.rs:56:21

Comment: i am getting this error

Comment: ./pages/query/[itmid].jsx
Error: failed to process

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241810/discussion-between-menu-cd-and-someone-special).